# How to delete printed line of file?

Tags: python, discord.py

my program read from `data.txt` file and print it on discord as replay to command, i want to delete printed code from `data.txt`. How to do this? Any ideas?
Atm code didn't work because read_coupon() return empty value (clear all txt file)

```
    @client.command()
    async def read_data(ctx, amount):
        await ctx.send(read_coupon(int(amount)))
```

```
def read_coupon(amount):
    result = ''
    with open("data.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f:
            result += line
            amount -= 1
            if line == result:
                line.replace(result," ")   

            if amount == 0: break            
    
    return result
```

```
data.txt:

uno
dos
tres
cuatro
cinco
seis
siete
ocho
nueve
diez
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the file, then add x lines to result and the other lines you write back to the file.

```
def read_coupon(amount):
    result = ''
    with open("kody.txt","r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("kody.txt","w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if amount!=0:
                result+=line
                amount-=1
            else:
                f.write(line)
    
    return result
```